# Straight line planar embedding of a graph structure

Tags: algorithm, graph, planar-graph

Here is my problem: I have a graph structure (with straight line edges) which I know to be planar (i.e. there exists an embedding of the graph where no edges cross). I need an algorithm which will take my graph and produce a straight line planar embedding of it. The algorithm does not need to be too efficient (an O(N^2) algorithm would do fine). Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

you may want at graphviz ( http://www.graphviz.org/ ). This will be able to draw it in many different formats and a pretty simple input definition. Several algorithms can be used to create graphs.

otherwise, scheck out Boyer-Myrvold planarity algorithm and assorted c code from wikipedia: http://jgaa.info/accepted/2004/BoyerMyrvold2004.8.3/planarity.zip

Answer (score 1):

Read this [document](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~rt/gdhandbook/chapters/planarity.pdf)...

I had this project for my Algorithms course, to embed the graph we used SVG format... once u decide the algorithm, SVG format is easy to generate...